# kapacitor recording needs to state task (noob needs understanding)

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

Sorry for the noob question but I can't seem to find an explanation of this. 
To make a kapacitor recording you use the following syntax

```
kapacitor record stream(or batch) -task <task-name> -duration 20s
```

Where  the time can be modified to your liking.

And to play back the recording you use something like:

```
kapacitor replay -recording <recording-id> -task <task-name-to-play-it-back-through>
```

From the documentation I am understanding that kapacitor recordings only record incoming DATA and you can play that data back through appropriate tasks. If that is the case,

1. why to you need to state a task name when you make the recording?
2. Can you play that data back through a different task that stated when making the recording.

Thanks to anyone who can help me better understand this.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. why to you need to state a task name when you make the recording?

The reason that the task name is needed when you make the recording, is so that Kapacitor knows which data to pull from. Which databases and retention policies, which measurements, etc.

> 2. Can you play that data back through a different task that stated when making the recording.

Yes.

Additionally, there's another type of recording called `query` that pulls data off of an InfluxDB query. Personally, I prefer to use the `query` recordings, that way I can be more deliberate about the data I'm using.

Comment: great explanation. Thank you. I will try query recordings also